# How to set height of row depend on 80 percentage height of main View/Display

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a view controller and a tableview inside of that. I want to set height of the row 80% of main view, Is there any method without using autolayout? Please help me to find the proper solution.

Comment: why don't you want to use Autolayout (programatically)? Too complicated?  Or is your XIB or Storyboard using old fashioned Springs & Struts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.view.frame.height * 0.8
}
```

substituted self.view for your mainView

ObjC if you need it:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    return (self.view.frame.size.height * 0.8);
}
```

The only problem with this answer, as Michael above has sort of indicated, there's absolutely nothing wrong with constraints and you really should be doing something like this with constraints. There's no guarantee that my solution is going to work for you because I can't garantee when the system is going to trigger a call to the cell height vs the mainView, and if the mainView's height isn't triggered FIRST, the you have a big problem on your hand because now your cells are height ZERO. It would be best, if you need a custom height for a cell, to subclass a cell, use autolayout like a boss, and do this the RIGHT way, but feel free to implement this method, it will work, but you now know when it won't work. Good luck

And should it not work, just say something, there's always people more than willing to help you through this, it's no big deal!